# How to properly construct this ruby query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a join query that executes fine until I call the method where it executes from a test.  The test is expecting to have 2 results so it's using the result.count and I get a syntax error near '*'.  Here's the query.

```
JobSearch.joins('inner join job_boards on job_searches.job_board_id = job_boards.id').select('job_searches.*, job_boards.job_board_name, job_boards.job_board_url, job_boards.send_emails_from').where('job_searches.cancelled_date is null and job_searches.created_at > ? and job_searches.email_address is not null and job_boards.active=?', DateTime.now - 90, true)
```

If I change job_searches.* to a field on that table like job_searches.keyword then I get the error - wrong number of arguments to function COUNT()  It's all coming from this test where the task.get_alerts method calls the query and the error is on the alerts.count line.

```
it 'returns alerts with a null cancelled_date' do
  alerts = task.get_alerts
  expect(alerts.count).to be(2)
end
```

So is there another way to construct this query to do the join which will allow it to return the proper results but also allow the test to count the results?

Comment: Can you take a step back and explain what you are trying to do?  Your code looks very complicated and rather than try to reverse-engineer and fix it, someone could offer a different, much more simple, solution.  Make sure you include any relevant schema details.

Comment: I am just trying to join two tables to get a search someone ran on a site. So the result set has their search info as well as the site info in each record.  Earlier in my test I set up some test records in the database with a couple that have a cancelled_date value so that they should not be returned when I run my test.  When the test runs, it expects to get 2 searches/alerts returned from the method.  Not trying to argue, but what seems so complicated?

Comment: The query basically just says "give me everything from job_searches, and a few additional fields from job_boards joining on the job_board.id where job_searches.cancelled_date is null and job_searches.email_address is not null and job_searches.created_at is within the last 90 days and job_board.active is true"

Comment: Well I found a solution to the problem.  I changed my test to cast the results to an array and check it's size rather than having rails run a count query due to the test  - expect(alerts.to_a.size).to be(2)